# How can I delete my alternate drive icon on the Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, desktop, icons

I'm using a system with a Windows drive and an Ubuntu drive (both physical, not virtual).  The Ubuntu Places menu lists a "320 GB file system" which is the Windows disk.

The same drive also appears as an icon on the desktop, but unlike everything else on the desktop, it does not appear in the directory listing of `~/Desktop`.

I think the icon was put on the desktop by accident and I never use it because the Places menu suffices. How can I delete this icon? Selecting then deleting does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide all the volumes from desktop:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/desktop/volumes_visible 'false'
```

Ripped from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=812457). If you want to hide specific volume, follow the link, there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use gconf-editor to disable showing mounted volumes on desktop. 
Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iNfdt20xsw)